# How to separate female and male without groupby() in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

It's a dataframes that each has Id, sex, age and so I.
I first seperate the age with id and sex.`

```python
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    age_distinct = titanic_df[['Sex','Age']].dropna()
    print age_distinct
```

get the result like this:

```python
       Sex   Age
0      male  22.0
1    female  38.0
2    female  26.0
3    female  35.0
4      male  35.0
6      male  54.0
7      male   2.0
8    female  27.0
9    female  14.0
10   female   4.0
11   female  58.0
12     male  20.0
13     male  39.0
14   female  14.0
15   female  55.0
16     male   2.0
18   female  31.0
20     male  35.0
21     male  34.0
22   female  15.0
23     male  28.0
24   female   8.0
25   female  38.0
27     male  19.0
30     male  40.0
33     male  66.0
34     male  28.0
35     male  42.0
37     male  21.0
38   female  18.0
..      ...   ...
856  female  45.0
857    male  51.0
```

But I don't know the next step.
How can I get a two set of data only include male and female

Comment: Please include an actual text snippet of the data here, not a picture.

Comment: `df[ df['Sex'] == 'female' ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
titanic_df[titanic_df['Sex'] == 'male']
```

This is basically a `SELECT * FROM titanic_df WHERE Sex == 'male'`, if you're familiar with SQL.

Edit: If you want to create two different `pandas.DataFrame` objects from each level of `Sex`, you can store each `DataFrame` in a dictionary, like this:

```
distinct_dfs = {}
for level in set(titanic_df['Sex']):
     level_df = titanic_df[titanic_df['Sex'] == level]
     distinct_dfs[level] = level_df
```

That's just one approach you could take, and would be advantageous with many different values for `Sex`. But, since you only have two values, this would be easiest:

```
female_df = titanic_df[titanic_df['Sex'] == 'female']
male_df = titanic_df[titanic_df['Sex'] == 'male']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print age_distinct[age_distinct.Sex == 'male']
print age_distinct.query('Sex == "male"')
```

Sample:

```
titanic_df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['male','female',np.nan],
                             'Age':[40,50,60]})

print (titanic_df)
   Age     Sex
0   40    male
1   50  female
2   60     NaN

age_distinct = titanic_df[['Sex','Age']].dropna()

print (age_distinct[age_distinct.Sex == 'male'])
    Sex  Age
0  male   40

print (age_distinct.query('Sex == "male"') )
    Sex  Age
0  male   40
```

Comment: Sure, btw, never use pictures instead of text, it cannot be copied and you get a lot downvotes. Better is use small sample - check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: It's my first time to post a question here, so I am sorry to use the wrong formation! Thanks for reminding! I will be careful next time.